# How can I Use Animation On Navigation Right bar button?

Tags: objective-c, animation, ios8, uinavigationbar

I am using below code for Navigation  right bar button:--

```
UIButton *settingsBtn =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [settingsBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_soft.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[settingsBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(settings) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [settingsBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(-16, -6, 95, 43)];

    UIView *rightBarButtonItems = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 76, 32)];
    //[rightBarButtonItems addSubview:homeBtn];
    [rightBarButtonItems addSubview:settingsBtn];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightBarButtonItems];
```

Now I want to use below code on same Navigation right bar button:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

 // Animation

    UIImageView*animationView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    animationView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:

                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.gif"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.gif"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.gif"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.gif"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.gif"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.gif"],nil];
    animationView.animationDuration = 1.25;
    animationView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [animationView startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:animationView];
}
```

How to work my navigation bar button like the below Images:---

[image]

Please send me suitable answer or provide me sample code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your code, with a little trick of mine and it work like magic.

```
NSArray *imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-0"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-1"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-2"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-3"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-4"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-5"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-6"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-7"],nil];

UIButton *barButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[barButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp-0"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // mine trick
[barButton.imageView setAnimationImages:imageArray];
[barButton.imageView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];

[barButton.imageView startAnimating];
[barButton sizeToFit];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:barButton];
```

**You need to give a image to barButton at first, so your button can make its frame**

[image: Screenshot of my test]